# SQL Search Without Full-Text Indexing

Tags: t-sql, full-text-search, azure-sql-database

We are in the process of migrating our application's database to Windows Azure SQL Database. Within the application, there are a couple of lightweight search functions, and we currently use T-SQL and full-text indexing to handle the searching. However, full-text indexing is not currently availabe in Azure.

I'm looking into non-SQL solutions such as Lucene.Net, which looks great, but I think it might be overkill for what we're trying to do. The datasets we're searching are not huge - on average less than 100,000 records - and there's only a few of them. An example table might look something like this...

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Items(
    [ItemID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Author] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Subject] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [ItemContent] [nvarchar](max) NULL, 
CONSTRAINT [PK_Items] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ItemID] ASC)
)
```

...where we want to search the Author, Subject and ItemContent fields. The Author and Subject can be multiple words, and the ItemContent field can be several paragraphs, so I don't see how I can avoid a Table Scan. The full-text index performed really well, and I'm not looking forward to doing:

SELECT ItemID FROM dbo.Items WHERE Author LIKE '%' + @SearchTerm + '%' OR Subject LIKE '%' + @SearchTerm + '%' OR ItemContent LIKE '%' + @SearchTerm + '%'

Any one have suggestions for ways to optimize this type of searching without using a full-text index?

Comment: what kind of searching are you looking to do... If you want to search something like "herman melville moby dick", lucene would catch this, but your your search query wouldn't... are you certain that you don't want a lucene-ish solution?

Comment: I do like Lucene as it is truly a "search" solution, and it is definitely in the running. That said, up until now our full-text index queries have worked well for this particular task - the queries tend to be quick filter-type queries as opposed to more complex search strings. So if I could get good performance out of a T-SQL solution I would lean in that direction.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to create, if not a full data warehouse solution, perhaps some denormalized tables that munged those columns into a single record (or fewer records)... So you'd have a db table w/ just ItemId|CombinedSearchableInfo where your CombinedSearchableInfo may be "Herman Melville Moby Dick", in which case you are doing less computational work (and you could use different query optimization techniques for something like that).  You would just need to maintain your search table w/ an off-line process...

Keep in mind though that Lucene can be help w/ things like misspellings and relevancy, and with a domain space like books and authors, misspellings are good and likely...

(Additionally, if you're going the azure route, you can lots of stuff now w/ table storage and blob storage... You could actually run your sql server w/ full text indexing as part of your blob storage and not have to retrofit anything... You would loose all performance benefits of azure sql, but hey... it's an option)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm looking into a similar alternative. What do you think about an indexed view instead of a table, where the "CombinedSearchableInfo" is the concatenated content from the columns I want to search? My understanding is that if I index the view and query it with (NOEXPAND) that it would essentially perform like a table. Of course, it would still be a  scan - I guess the hope is that if the scan is looking at just one column, it would perform better.